# Hide IME Window in Chrome on OSX

Tags: jquery, macos, ime

I'm trying to hide the IME (input method engine) window on Chrome via Javascript. It appears when I have the IME type set to something like Katakana, type something in (say 'do') and then click down in the box after it changes to the proper character.

The closest I got to hiding this window was a hack like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/8ofc47r7/1/

```
$('input').blur();
```

It seems to me like the event to display the IME window is fired before the jQuery $.keyDown event, so even if I set the keyDown event to return false, I'll still get a flicker of the window.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript or jQuery, you can do it setting the attribute `type` to `tel`.

Using CSS, you can try one of this, or both: (all depends on your chrome version!)

```
-webkit-ime-mode:disabled;
ime-mode: disabled;
```

This solution is working for me. In case is not working for you, you can add the `!important` attribute.

Just remember that the syntax for ime in case of using chrome is:

```
-webkit-ime-mode: auto | active | inactive | disabled
ime-mode: auto | active | inactive | disabled
```

The appropriate value in your case should be: `disabled` for both properties. One important thing: **currently, only inline style (e.g. `<input style="ime-mode: disabled;">`) is supported. External CSS or `<style></style>` tag are not supported**.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: [Leonidas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/193856/leonidas) I just re-edit the answer. Check if it works for you.